# 'NoneType' Error when using a Try and Except Block

Tags: python, exception, null-pointer, invalid-argument

I'm having a strange issue with a try and except block I'm using to catch invalid data entry into a simple Black Jack Game I'm writing.....

```
def PickNumberOfPlayers():
    global log

    try:
        inputs = int(input("How Many Players Would You Like?: "))
        PlayersNumber = inputs
        log.write("How Many Players Would You Like?: \n")
        return PlayersNumber

    except ValueError:
        print("Try Typing in A Valid Number")
        log.write("Try Typing in A Valid Number\n")
        PickNumberOfPlayers()
```

I then have a method GameStart() which starts a number of method calls:

```
def GameStart():
    global ListOfPlayers

    for i in range(0, int(PickNumberOfPlayers())):
        name = input("What Would You Like This Players Name To Appear As?:")
        ListOfPlayers.update({name: Player(0, name)})

    for key, value in ListOfPlayers.items():
        value.AccountSetup()
        value.Bet()

    for key, value in ListOfPlayers.items():
        value.PlayerDeal()
    Dealer.Deal()
```

When I run the code and enter proper values ( a valid integer) there is no issue.  When I first enter a invalid number (a string or char) I get the appropriate message "*Try Typing in A Valid Number*, and then when I do enter a valid integer I get the error -

```
    for i in range(0, int(PickNumberOfPlayers())):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Any idea?

Comment: `global` is not necessary here. Avoid recursion. Use a while loop instead. For logging, there is the logging module, which can write on screen and to file at the same time. Instead of update use index: `ListOfPlayers[name] = Player(0, name)`. Avoid `global` in general.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `PickNumberOfPlayers()` in your `except`, you do not return its value.  Do `return PickNumberOfPlayers()` instead.

Comment: When I call the function recursively after a failed attempt, the function should loop through itself from the beginning and ask for a value, parse it and then return it....is that not what happens?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify PickNumberOfPlayers to always return an int.

```
def PickNumberOfPlayers():
    global log

    while 1:
        try:
            return int(input("How Many Players Would You Like?: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Try Typing in A Valid Number")
            log.write("Try Typing in A Valid Number\n")
```